# Can't see new Unity Spread since upgrade to 12.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, 12.10

That's the problem, I upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 yesterday. I've read lots of articles where is said that "the new Spread is so cool" and stuff, but I can't see it properly. For example, it should look like this:

[image]

But instead, what I see is this:

[image]

As you can see, there are some differences, for example, I can't see the "ghost new window option".

So, is there a way to fix this? May be upgrade some package, or something, I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the image you link to isn't the new spread, it's a mockup of what the new spread would look like. The spread in 12.10 is the same as it's always been.

No new spread (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The new spread you are hearing about is not for every window (The Super + W one), but for several windows from *one* application.

When you have several windows of the same type (application/program) you can click on the app in the sidebar to get the new spread.

So for instance you have 4 firefox windows (not tabs) open. To get the spread you are talking about you need to click on the firefox icon in the dock.